# How to make stdout and stderr work for command used by other application?

Tags: python

I would like to use stdout and stderr to determine if there's some error message used by a command provided by some other application. I can make it work for system command such as below.

```
size_permission = Popen([ "ls" , "-l" , '/home/jnh.txt' ] , stdout=subprocess.PIPE , stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

If the file /home/jnh.txt does not exists, there's an output in stderr as shown below:

```
>>> for tst in size_permission.stderr:
...  print tst
...
ls: /home/bta/jnh.txt: No such file or directory
```

Then the stdout does not have any output which is expected.

```
>>> for tst in size_permission.stdout:
...  print tst
...
```

Now, I want to have the same behavior with other applications command. I tried but even if the "other application command" has an error message, there's always an output in stdout instead in stderr ? Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: It's possible the other program incorrectly prints error messages to `stdout` instead of `stderr`.

Comment: Hi mipadi, ok thnks..is there other way ?

Comment: If the other program sends output to stderr only, you'll have to parse the output for what you want (or get them to fix the program).

Comment: I think i will check the return code instead. Thanks a lot!